# Why is there no "quantization" tag yet?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

First of all sorry if this doesn't belong here, or if i'm a newbie and i'm out of line, etc. But i was wondering why no one has created the quantization tag yet?
Is it perhaps, because no one really cares about it? or no one ever asks a question abut it? I searched for the word, and there are some questions with the word in the title, which ask explanation on exactly that phenomenon in different applications,and also a bunch of others that just mention it in the body of the text.

I feel like the general topic of quantization, finite precision processing (which strangely is the only thing that can be done in the real world) is always discarded or left aside as something obvious.

So more than just asking if someone with enough reputation could create it, i am also asking: Don't you think that if every book on DSP mentions the Nyquist Sampling theorem, and sampling is a very basic concept in signal processing, shouldn't quantization be also?

Comment: I finally reached the barrier of reputation in order to be able to create tags and add the quantization tag. So i did. If anyone still wants to follow the discusssion, you are more than welome to do so.